# SoundCloud says sound is streamable but won't play on iOS or OS X

Tags: ios, stream, soundcloud

I'm writing an app for iOS 7 only that uses SoundCloud. But the problem here is that sometimes I fetch sounds that have the streamable property set to TRUE, the stream URL but I'm not able to play it. The player simply hangs. This also happens on OS X.

I know that a couple of sounds from SoundCloud are streamable only with Flash. But if you use the mobile version of the site, then all songs are streamable, even those that needed Flash to run on the desktop version.

What I want to know is how can I play those sounds since they are supposed to be streamable?

One of the sounds that shows this happening is this one:
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/99350098/stream?client_id=[YOUR CLIENT ID HERE]

Thanks,

Abras

Answer (score 1):

From other posts it seems SoundCloud have changed/are in the process of changing the protocol they use for streaming between http and rtmp. The problem being that rtmp is flash, which obviously won’t work on iOS and possibly on osx (flash is not install by default).

You can check by going to /streams (not /stream)

A check (http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/99350098/streams?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID) of the track you gave above, this returns a rtmp url.

Comment: the problem is that even we change to `streams` there is still a problem we get the object but it isn't playing if there is any idea about how to fix it in JavaScript with their SDK